# I want to run SketchUp 2014 which is already installed in the Windows partition with wine

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, wine, proprietary

SketchUp 2014 is already installed (and is working under Windows) in a Windows partition on the computer. Ubuntu (12.04 Precise) is also installed in another partition.

Simply running SketchUp through wine (got with `apt-get install wine`) doesn't give a usable program; like this:

```
wine /mnt/diskc/Program\ Files/SketchUp/SketchUp\ 2014/SketchUp.exe
```

What should be done to make it work?

#### The problems are:

1. it doesn't find some libraries (DLLs);
2. it doesn't find the "license file";
3. SketchUp still gets into an unresponsive state after passing the initial setup dialog after solving the previous problems.

Generally, SketchUp is expected to be usable under wine according to various reports on the web; see http://wiki.winehq.org/Sketchup?action=show&redirect=GoogleSketchup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default way to install wine is

```
apt-get install wine
```

which installs wine-1.6.2 in Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty) (and an even older version in 14.04 (Precise)).

First of all, to be safe and not to damage any data in the Windows partition (which is NTFS) when doing this, I re-mount it read-only:

```
# umount /mnt/diskc
# mount /mnt/diskc -o ro
#
```

#### 1: Required DLLs

To solve Problem 1, in 12.04 (Precise), I had to copy/symlink a library into wine's disk C:

```
$ ln -s /mnt/diskc/Windows/System32/mfc100u.dll ~/.wine/drive_c/windows/system32/
```

#### 2: Finding the "license file"

To solve Problem 2, in 12.04 (Precise), I had to copy/symlink a special SketchUp's data file into wine's disk C:

```
$ ln -s /mnt/diskc/ProgramData/SketchUp/SketchUp\ 2014/SketchUp14.lf ~/.wine/drive_c/users/Public/Application\ Data/SketchUp/SketchUp\ 2014/SketchUp14.lf
```

...creating the parent directories as needed (`mkdir -p ~/.wine/drive_c/users/Public/Application\ Data/SketchUp/SketchUp\ 2014`).

Or perhaps I should have symlinked/copied the whole directory with the data (to re-use those settings):

```
$ ln -s /mnt/diskc/ProgramData/SketchUp ~/.wine/drive_c/users/Public/Application\ Data/
```

#### 3: SketchUp not responding after startup

This turned out to be [another known problem (see under "Tips")](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/install-google-sketchup-ubuntu1404/) (found via "[Sketchup not responding](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2253756)").

(BTW, **my solution is primarily based on that post http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/install-google-sketchup-ubuntu1404/.** I wrote my answer because I wanted to add some corrections and more precise current information to that post. Big thanks!)

At this point, one can decide to overcome this problem at the cost of disabling the Ruby engine in SketchUp by running it similarly to:

```
$ wine /mnt/diskc/Program\ Files/SketchUp/SketchUp\ 2014/SketchUp.exe /DisableRubyAPI
```

This problem must already have been (imperfectly) [fixed in wine-1.7.31](https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=34941#c12); this version or later [is available in the Ubuntu Wine repository](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages?batch=75&memo=75&start=75) for 14.04 (Trusty) or later, so I'd need to upgrade from my 12.04 (Precise) to Trusty to use those packages.

The version which comes with the official Ubuntu Trusty repositories (wine-1.6.2, as told above) is not suitable.

### The experience of using wine1.7 from the PPA

First, I upgraded the whole system to 14.04 (Trusty). Then, to use the wine package from PPA in 14.04 (Trusty):

```
# apt-get purge 'wine.*'
# apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
# apt-get update
# apt-get install wine1.7
```

(Surprizingly, although `apt-get install wine1.7` did install a version of `wine-mono` and `wine-gecko` as dependencies, they didn't match the requirements of the `wine` program from the package, as brought to light by the warnings when `winecfg` was run; and I had to apt-get-install manually other (newer) versions of these packages. Reported as [a winehq bug](https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39226).)

The above solutions for Problems 1 & 2 had also to be applied when using wine1.7 from the PPA for Trusty.

(The version for 14.04 (Trusty) was `1.7.50-0ubuntu1`; then I also tried all this on 14.10 (Utopic), and the version of wine provided by the PPA for 14.10 (Utopic) was `1.7.44-0ubuntu1`, so an older version than for Trusty, and hence--of course--needing the fix for Problem 1 (DLLs), too.)